# How to build a CSS dial guage dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. How can I add the grey dial underneath like in the picture below?
   [image]

2. I have created a dial that shows 100%. I was wondering if I can write a function to dynamically render the %(may be by using a math.random function)?

```css
.ring {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#C816CDFF 0, #C816CDFF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(#C816CDFF 0, #C816CDFF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(white 0, white 66%, transparent 66%),
  conic-gradient(#C816CDFF 0, #c816cd 150deg, white 60deg, white 200deg, #C816CDFF 210deg, #C816CDFF 360deg);
  background-size: 5.0% 5.0%, 5.0% 5.0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 27.2% 95.6%, 75.5% 94.2%, center center, center center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: none;
}


.speed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}

.speed .number {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.speed .units {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div className="App">
      <div class="ring">
        <div class="speed">
          <div class="number">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="units" >100%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have the purple line.. so why not just have a grey one underneath?

Comment: I am unable to layer them on top of each other. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would have a parent element with relative positioning, then the grey ring with absolute positioning, then the colored-in ring with absolute positioning, same with the text then as well. In my experience it works better if you have a parent element just for the position and then styling happens with the children elements.

Comment: at this point I am almost on the verge of considering SVGs for this use case, could probably add a touch of animation to it as well, like on speedtest.net

Comment: Ah yes, as long as IE11 is of no concern [see caniuse svg](https://caniuse.com/svg) that's totally viable.